# How to get multiple return object values from Wep API?

Tags: c#

My Wep API method :

```
    [HttpGet]
            public object getData()
            {
              var firstObj = dbContext.Customer();
              var secondObj= dbContext.Department();
              var thirdObj= dbContext.Email();
              return new { firstObj,secondObj,thirdObj };
            }

    /* this is my client side call */
     using (var client = new HttpClient())
      {
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", CommonHelper.CurrentToken);
         client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CommonHelper.baseAddress);
         HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/OPUS/Accounts/getData");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
}
```

I have returned multiple objects from different tables. I need to get those values from single method in `WEP API`

Comment: If the objects are unrelated, why do you want to get them all at once? - What is the reason you don't want to have three separate web methods?

Comment: You can encapsulate them as a single object and return to client end.

Comment: I need to get all the values without creating separate web methods, i mean don't want create different service call from client

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of the following, passing back a single anonymous object containing enough of your values:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage getData()
{
  var firstObj = dbContext.Customer();
  var secondObj= dbContext.Department();
  var thirdObj= dbContext.Email();
  return new { firstObj,secondObj,thirdObj };
}

    /* this is my client side call */
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", CommonHelper.CurrentToken);
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CommonHelper.baseAddress);
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/OPUS/Accounts/getData");
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can able to get all the objects through single WEB API Method.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", CommonHelper.CurrentToken);
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CommonHelper.baseAddress);
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("/OPUS/Accounts/getData");
       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 

var Lookups = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                    JObject _jObject = JObject.Parse(Lookups.ToString());

                    JArray deptStatus = _jObject["firstObj"] as JArray;
                    DeptTypeLookups = deptStatus .ToObject<ObservableCollection<Department>>();

JArray custStatus = _jObject["secondObj"] as JArray;
                    custTypeLookups = custStatus .ToObject<ObservableCollection<CustDetail>>();
}
```

Thanks